# Get Value of each Element of all Row and Column of a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Well, I have a table  with differents elements like textbox, textarea and checkbox.

I am using this code:

```
$('#tablaCorrectiva tr').not(':first').each(function() {
alert($(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").val()); //Get BLANK
alert($(this).children("td:nth-child(1)")); // GET "[object Object]"
}
```

But I don't get the value of the element.

I tried with:

```
$(this).children("td:nth-child(3)").find('.acc_correc').val()
```

But I get undefined.

Please Help

Comment: `td` elements dont have a `value` attribute, hence a blank value returned. Can you post your HTML as we need to see your DOM structure to see how to traverse it.

Comment: please provide HTML code

Comment: By any chance are these fields in the table the only ones in a wrapping form? If so you can extract the "successful" form control values much easier using `$('#myForm').serialize();` (which handles the different form types, multiplicity, disabled controls, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

`alert($(this).children("td:nth-child(3)").find(':input').val());`

Comment: Works! whit textbox but not with textarea

Answer (score 0):

use

```
alert($(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").html());
```

instead of

```
alert($(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").val());
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzb6M/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this cod

```
<table id=tablaCorrectiva >
<thead>
<tr><th>code</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input value="pippo"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="pluto"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="paperino"></td></tr>
</tbody>
<table>

/*Suppose the first TR is head and it is under <thead></thead>*/
$('#tablaCorrectiva > tbody > tr > td').each(function(index,value) {
alert($(value).find("textarea,input").val()); 
});
```